# Understanding DSL: multiple PPPoE connections

Tags: linux, dsl, pppoe

I have a DSL modem that I have set to bridging mode and connected to a Linux computer. In my setting, the Linux computer negotiates the PPPoE part of the connection and gets an IP address.

What if I were to connect a second computer to the same modem (and naturally obtain a second public IP address from the service provider)? Should the second computer negotiate a second PPPoE connection or how would that work?

The question may not make sense because I am not perfectly familiar with the concepts.

EDIT: with the DSL modem I have, a ZTE ZXHN H267A, if my memory serves me well, I do not have the luxury of getting a conversion from a DSL link to a neat Ethernet switch. I can either run the modem in bridging mode, set up a PPPoE connection with NetworkManager and enjoy a public IP address, or I can set the modem to routing **and** NAT mode and be stuck with a private network address. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: In practice, this is not the way ive ever seen it done. Generally if you need more then 1 IP, your provider will route a subnet (block) of IPs across your connection, and you then typically configure the LAN interface of the router to use these IPs

Answer (score 4):

> What if I were to connect a second computer to the same modem (and naturally obtain a second public IP address from the service provider)? Should the second computer negotiate a second PPPoE connection or how would that work?

Yes, it would have to negotiate a second PPPoE connection. Activating PPPoE doesn't reconfigure the Ethernet link itself – it establishes a tunnel connection on top of it. A second computer could not participate in it, but it could establish a second tunnel of its own.

(In fact the way PPPoE works is *very* similar to connecting to a VPN server, and the "PPP" in PPPoE is even exactly the same protocol as in PPTP or some other VPN types. It just happens to be running over raw Ethernet here.)

However, many ISPs will not allow this. Often they have either a limit of 1 PPPoE session per physical customer line, or 1 public IP address per customer, or something like that – so the 2nd session might either fail or kick the 1st one out. (Some ISPs *do* allow multiple sessions.)

Also, the two computers will not become part of the same LAN (as the underlying Ethernet interface usually doesn't have any IP addresses and is for PPPoE only). They will have fully independent WAN connections to the ISP.